# Apache htaccess rewrite condition to root folder on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create a rewrite condition to route to a different folder on my server.

something like this 
`http://mydomain.com/newapp/(.*)$`

should rewrite to `/var/www/mynewapp/index.php/$1`

i can't for the life of me figure out how to write that conditions, no matter what i do it stays in my current app....

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^newapp/(.*)$ /var/www/mynewapp/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

that's what i've tried but as i said keeps redirecting back to the original app.

Answer (score 0):

If the `/var/www/mynewapp/index.php` is not within the original DocumentRoot (which seems like the case), I would just symlink `/var/www/myoldapp/newindex.php` to `/var/www/mynewapp/index.php` and use something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^newapp
RewriteRule ^newapp/(.*)$ newindex.php [L]
```

to redirect the requests.